# single instance of an activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I know single instance can be achived by setting `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`    in menifest file. but i want to do it on run time . I think it can be achived by setting **FLAG** but not sure witch one.. plzz help me.. thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use `singleInstance` launch mode. That is for HOME-screen replacements only. Please explain in more detail what your work flow is and where you are getting multiple instances when you really want only one.

Comment: in my activity i have a listview witch i populate by taking value from database. and some other buttons to launch new activity like filter etc.. i import values to the database from csv file in sdcard on clicking import button this is where i dont want the same instant  i want to recreate the activity. hope i made clear..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general you can use a combination of `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`, `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to accomplish what you want. However, which one (or ones) to use depends on the situation you have.

Comment: tried ur suggestion and FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT it working fine for now. Let me test it for few more scenario.

Answer (score 4):

This is what u are looking for

```
Intent intent= new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

UPDATE: `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` may also be needed in Manifest

Comment: no its not working.Still when i come back to my activity by setting those flag onCreate() method is still executing witch was not happening when i hardcoded  it in menifest.

Answer (score 1):

*singleInstance* specifies that the launched or recycled activity will be created on a new or existing task, and **no other activities can be stacked on top of it**. The system will ensure any activities started from it are put on other tasks.

1 task and 1 activity.

There is no intent flag that I know of that will prevent further activities launched by your activity without having to specify flags in all of your new activity's created intents.

So the answer is **this is not possible**.

Previous posted answers imitate how this will look, but the behavior goes against the specification.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve singleInstance behaviour with this flags Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks. But i moved on from android development long  time back.